# How to prevent a jQuery Mobile collapsible from expanding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, preventdefault

I'm working with the JQM collapsibleset widget.

I need one collapsible to just be a button (that allows to add more elements to the set/accordeon), so when it's clicked, it should NOT expand (or collapse).

I'm using the following code to no avail:

```
 $("div.ui-dynamic-tabs div.tab_add").on("collapsiblebeforeexpand", function (e) {

      e.stopPropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
      console.log("foo");
 });
```

with both the `collapsibleexpand` and the `collapsiblebeforeexpand` custom event I added to JQM to test whether this would help.

I can register all events and returning false also does prevent the console from being triggered. However... the collapsible still expands... :-(

I thought adding a `beforeexpand` event would prevent the subsequent code inside JQM to run when calling `preventDefault` on the event, but it still executes.

**Question:**
How do I stop the collapsible from expanding correctly by prevent execution of an event triggered before the expanding javascript is run?

PS: I'm also tagging with jQueryUI because both JQM and UI use the same widget factory and event mechanisms.

Comment: jqm 1.4a2 isn't listening to `collapse` and `expand` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HXAU6/

Comment: @Omar: as per [latest](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js) code there is both an `expand` and `collapse` event (look for `this._trigger( isCollapse ? "collapse" : "expand" );`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery Mobile 1.3.2, that event is called [collapsibleexpand](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand), and its default behavior can indeed be prevented.

You only have to write:

```
$("div.ui-dynamic-tabs div.tab_add").on("collapsibleexpand", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @frequent, indeed, I looked at the source code and 1.4a2 does not check whether the `collapse` and `expand` events have been default-prevented anymore. This is not mentioned in the list of changes though, so maybe it will be fixed in 1.4 proper.

Comment: I don't get this to work even in jQM 1.3.2, the event seems just to be called 'expand'. Can anybody please enlighten me why I cannot lock it again after uplocking it once here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwil/a46rr)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6427) is the solution from JQM on Github:

```
$.widget( "mobile.collapsible", $.mobile.collapsible, {
  _handleExpandCollapse: function( isCollapse ) {
    if ( this._trigger( "collapsiblebefore" +
      ( isCollapse ? "collapse" : "expand" ) ) ) {

          this._superApply( arguments );
     }
    }
});
```

Comment: this should be added before loading jqm?

Comment: No after. Put it in a file like `extensions.js` and load it after, because you are adding to the widget, so it needs to be loaded

Comment: I can't get this to work, how do you register the events afterwards? Do you have to modify the collapsible in some way? I simply don't see events (assuming it is called collapsiblebeforeexpand :-)

Comment: The code is wrong. "collapsiblebefore" should just read "before". Then  use the on method to bind "collapsiblebeforeexpand" or "collapsiblebeforecollapse"

Comment: @DaveNottage: that was some time ago. JQM code has changed since, so feel free to post the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per frequent's answer, this is a modification that suits JQM 1.4:

```
$.widget('mobile.collapsible', $.mobile.collapsible, {
  _handleExpandCollapse: function(isCollapse) {
    if (this._trigger('before' + (isCollapse ? 'collapse' : 'expand'))) {
      this._superApply(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

Bind the event:

```
$('#mycollapsible div').on('collapsiblebeforeexpand', function(event, ui) {
  if (someCondition)
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent node from expanding
});
```